# How to prove or model check a theorem in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

The below module declares a set of numbers that are in the range 10 to 99 that are divisible by 2 only once and call it `NumbersThatDivideBy2Once`. At the end it declares a theorem that the constant `input` is a subset of `NumbersThatDivideBy2Once`.

```
--------------------------- MODULE TestModule ---------------------------
EXTENDS Naturals

CONSTANT input

Numbers == { n \in Nat : n > 9 /\ n < 100 }

DividesBy2(n) == (n % 2) = 0

DividesBy2Once(n) == DividesBy2(n) /\  ~DividesBy2(n \div 2)

NumbersThatDivideBy2Once == { n \in Numbers: DividesBy2Once(n) }

THEOREM input \subseteq NumbersThatDivideBy2Once

=======================
```

How can I check if this theorem holds for a given input? If I run a model check with a provided set of numbers as `input`, even if some of those numbers are not part of `NumbersThatDivideBy2Once` I still get no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your theorem a name,

> ```
> THEOREM T == input \subseteq NumbersThatDivideBy2Once
> ```

Go to the "Model Checking Results" tab, and in "Evaluate Constant Expression" introduce `T`, in order for it to be evaluated.

---

Your model checker needs to be told what to do with the specification file, which is essentially a just collection of mathematical definitions.

In "normal use" you want to provide TLC a temporal formula representing your specification (usually given the name`Spec` in the specification file). You introduce it in the "model overview" tab, under "what is the behaviour spec?". And that is what TLC uses to perform model checking.

In this case you don't have that. So just keep the option "no behaviour spec" and, as indicated above, specify in the "Model Checking Results" tab the constant expression you want to evaluate.